# How to evaluate particle fluctuations in BCS theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity

I'm trying to evaluate particle fluctuations in BCS theory and I've been able to explicitly calculate the average total particle number by taking the expected value of the number operator (in particular the summation of all the number operators for every k-value). However, the calculation involving the fluctuations is proving to be difficult and I can't seem to get the correct value:

$$\langle N^2 \rangle - \langle N \rangle^2 =\sum_k(v_k^2\cdot u_k^2)$$

How do I do this correctly?
the procedure i used is the following:

$$\langle N \rangle = 2\sum_k(v_k^2) \Rightarrow (\langle N \rangle)^2= 4\sum_{k,l}(v_k^2)(v_l^2) $$

then we must evaluate the average of $N^2$ so:
$$\langle N^2 \rangle= \langle (\sum_{k,\sigma} n_{k\sigma})^2 \rangle = \langle (\sum_{k} c_{k,\uparrow}^+ c_{k,\uparrow} + c_{k,\downarrow}^+ c_{k,\downarrow} )^2  \rangle = 4\langle (\sum_{k} c_{k,\uparrow}^+ c_{k,\uparrow})^2  \rangle$$

where i used the fact that all electrons occur in pair with antiparallel spin (procedure found oon Tinkham's book)
we can write this quantity as

$$4\langle (\sum_{k} c_{k,\uparrow}^+ c_{k,\uparrow})^2  \rangle= 4\sum_{k,l} \langle c_{k,\uparrow}^+ c_{k,\uparrow} c_{l,\uparrow}^+ c_{l,\uparrow} \rangle = \\
=4\sum_{k,l} \langle \phi_0|(u_k^*+v_k^*c_{-k,\downarrow} c_{k,\uparrow})(u_l^*+v_l^*c_{-l,\downarrow} c_{l,\uparrow})c_{k,\uparrow}^+ c_{k,\uparrow} c_{l,\uparrow}^+ c_{l,\uparrow} (u_k+v_kc_{k,\uparrow}^+ c_{-k,\downarrow}^+)(u_l+v_lc_{l,\uparrow}^+ c_{-l,\downarrow}^+)|\phi_0\rangle $$

where i used the BCS ground state:

$$|\psi_G\rangle= \prod_k(u_k+v_kc_{k,\uparrow}^+ c_{-k,\downarrow}^+)|\phi_0\rangle $$

and where all the brackets in the product with indexes different from l,k where dropped since in the average give a unitary factor. (this reasoning was used in the calculation of $\langle N \rangle$, which proved to be successful, maybe the mistake is here?)
Now, by inspection, one can notice few things:

- expliciting the product of the brackets on the right, it's clear that only the terms containing $v_k$ will remain, in fact the terms containing $u_k$ don't have any creation operator and therefore the annihilation operators in between the 2 pair of brackets  will act on the vacuum state and give 0. Also the mixed products will have the same fate because now we will have 1 pair of creation operators (say with index k) that will thus be counted by the k number operator, but then the number operator l will again give 0 acting on the vacuum state.
- the action of the number operators in the middle gives a unitary factor for the remaining terms, so that now we have the product of the pair of brackets on the left against the term containing only $v_k$ and $v_l$ .
- this term also have 2 pairs of creation operators with indexes l,k, and the only term not averaging to 0  when expliciting this product is the one containing also 2 pairs of annihilation operators l,k neutralizing the action of the creation operators.

so in the end i get something like

$$\langle N^2 \rangle= 4\sum_{k,l}(v_k^2)(v_l^2)$$

which is exactly the result already obtained for $ {\langle N \rangle}^2 $,so that the particle fluctuations $\langle N^2 \rangle - \langle N \rangle^2$ gives zero. Where am i missing something? the correct result contains the square of $u_k,v_k$ so i guess i should focus on the case where l=k but i cannot get to the bottom of the question.

Comment: Can you clarify how exactly you've tried to do the calculation and where it's not working?   Currently, you just gave what seems to be a general formula.

Comment: well, i updated my question including, correctly formatted, all my calculations, but my question has been closed and i don't know how to re-open it

Comment: The problem now I think is that you've provided more details than necessary and it's hard to narrow down where specifically you're stuck.  It's a hard balance to strike.